# How to select rated voltage of a RF capacitor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, rf

For example, GSM low band PA output around 33dBm, I need to put a dc block (33pF) on my design. The cap vendor has rated voltage 6.3V, 25V, 50V. How to choose it? Is 6.3V ok for the design?

Comment: Equally important with the voltage is the impedance at the frequency of interest. Rather than say GSM low band, you should state the frequency. I am not sure what GSM low band is.

Comment: Yes, it's 50ohm system. 
GSM low band is around 850~900MHz

Comment: If this is a DC block, you should not have to worry about RF voltage too much - unless an error occurs, the full RF voltage shouldn't be over your capacitor. (ofcourse, you want to know what will happen if the output is not what you expect it to be and you get reflections etc.). Also look at the DC component here as well. In your band of interest, your capacitor is only an impedance of 5-6 ohm, compared to the 50 ohm source and load impedance (I assume that is what they are?).

Comment: ATC American Technical Ceramics is one source. You want a low-loss capacitor, right?

Answer (score 1):

Rough calculation: -

A 33 pF capacitor at 850 MHz has an impedance of about 6 ohms. If it is passing a power of 33 dBm (about 2 watts) to a 50 ohm load, the voltage seen across the 50 ohm is \$\sqrt{2\times 50}\$ = 10 volts RMS.

The 50 ohm current will be 200 mA RMS and this will drop a peak voltage of about 1.7 volts across the series 33 pF capacitor.

So if the DC voltage plus the peak voltage is well below the capacitors rated voltage then you should be OK.